# How to handle fsck 'Operational error'?

Tags: fsck

From a bootable USB stick I loaded ubuntu and ran

```
fsck /dev/sda
```

and the output is

```
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
...

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sda
```

and the process ended with error code 8. Now what to do next?

Comment: You should run `fsck` against the partition/LVM/cryptDevcie that holds the filesystem not the whole disk. It is possible that a filesystem is put onto a whole disk without partitions, but from the output it looks like you have partitions on `/dev/sda`. To get an overview you can run `lsblk` or `parted /dev/sda print`.

Comment: Or maybe I need to use `sda1` instead of just `sda`?

Comment: Exactly what I tried to say. But depends on which partition you want to check.

Comment: Then the original page I was following was imcomplete. Its `sda2` in my case. Thanks this is working now, but of course I have more questions...